# How can ignore accents (intonation) on characters in php?

Tags: php, search

I have a textbox search form and the word " **Περισσότερα** ".

The word "**ρισσότ**" contains a Greek character with intonation: **" ό "**.

After I click on the submit button the program searches for " **ρισσότ** " and returns results like this:

> Πε**ρισσότ**ερα σχετικά με την τοποθεσία

When i type the word "**ρισσοτ**" without intonation, my program finds my word and shows it in the results but doesn't make it bold.

> Περισσότερα σχετικά με την τοποθεσία

How can I make my program highlight the match in bold?

My PHP is this

```
$search_array = explode(' ', $search);
foreach ($search_array as $k => $v)
{
    $w = trim($v);
        if ($w)
    {
       $result[$i]['description'] = preg_replace('/(' . preg_quote($w, '/') . ')/siU', '<b>\\1</b>', $result[$i]['description']);
    }
}
```

Comment: You probably want to replace all the accented characters with the non accented equivalent. There are many resources in the net about this. Also, this may work: http://php.net/manual/en/class.collator.php

Comment: I need a new example from above example

Comment: With this answer the program replace the ό with o i don't wont to replace it but i show it as is but bold.

Comment: The first few results for "php regex ignore accents" on Google all point to similar questions on this site. As @fedorqui says above, you will need to replace the accented characters with non-accented ones, or you could try this solution: http://stackoverflow.com/a/10837628/1255289

Comment: No this is a bad way, and is not working for me, and if it is, is a bad way!

Answer (score -2):

```
$search_array = explode(' ', $search);
foreach ($search_array as $k => $v)
{
    $w=trim($v);
    if($w)
      $result[$i]['description'] = '<b>'.$w.'</b>';

}
```

Comment: This is the same code of my code, without preg_replace('/(' . preg_quote and i needed that. And with your code replace ό with o and show my only specify word